# SAS Macro by week

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to convert the below macro into a loop so I can enter the start and end date in order to create weekly tables for that date range. Currently I have to run the macro multiple times by entering the start and end dates individually for each week.

```
%macro tb(start_, end_);

PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE tbl_&start_. AS
select a.id,
  &start_. as wk,
  case when a.id=b.id then 1 else 0 end as flg

from tb1 a left join (select  id
                      from tb1
                     where cdate <= &start_.
                     ) b
           on a.id=b.id
where orderdate <= &end_.

;

QUIT;

%mend ;


%tb(03JAN2021, 09JAN2021) ;
%tb(10JAN2021, 16JAN2021) ;
%tb(17JAN2021, 23JAN2021) ;
```

Comment: Would you mind to make this intelligable by explaining in words what it does?

Comment: Does the current code work?  I don't see how as `03JAN2011` is not valid as either a variable name nor a constant to use as the value for the WK variable you are creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [INTCK](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p1md4mx2crzfaqn14va8kt7qvfhr.htm#n1xl65p32ogosyn199i6i151bw4d) and [INTNX](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm) functions could be helpful for this task. The following generates a dataset with start and end dates for all weeks in the specified time interval.

```
data weeks;
  /* Specify start and end. */
  start_date = "01FEB2022"d;
  end_date = "28FEB2022"d;
  /* Calculate number of weeks. */
  num_weeks = intck("week", start_date, end_date);
  /* Iterate over weeks. */
  do i = 0 to num_weeks - 1;
    /* Get the sunday in the week i. */
    start_week = intnx("week", start_date, i);
    /* Add six days = end of week. */
    end_week = intnx("days", start_week, 6);
    /* If you need, convert into character. */
    start_ = put(start_week, date.);
    end_ = put(end_week, date.);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

If you want weeks starting at mondays you should use "week.2" instead of "week". You could also do e.g. bi-weekly reports... Just check the documentation for [Date and Time intervals](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p0syn64amroombn14vrdzksh459w.htm).

Now you can run your macro via call execute.

```
data _null_;
  set weeks;
  call execute('%nrstr(%do_for_each_week('||start_||', '||end_||'))');
run;
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to insert the `call execute` statement in the first `data`-step where you now execute the `output`-statement?

Comment: No, I did that just to separate the steps in case one wants to look at the list of dates.